# SBS 2003 requires logon for share

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory

Win 2003 SBS has started requiring password for a domain user. It's weird because it doesn't requires it every time...sometimes it will work (automatic shares through logon script) and sometimes it won't...lets the user in after 2-3 tries (wrong password errors) and the loads the share with the same pass...

Thanks!

Comment: And the logs are empty!

Answer (score 0):

Is it just for a particular user?  What if that user tries accessing the share from another computer?  To see exactly what is happening, capture a network trace with NetMon or WireShark and see what error the server is sending back to the client.